# how to update slider position when it is moved in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, slider, matlab-figure

I created a matlab video player, and I had problem in the slider.When I moved the slider,though video was paused, the slider snapped back to the position before I dragged it. So is there a way for me to get the value of the slider at position where I drag it to ? then, I can use that value to change the frame played accordingly

This is the slider callback function

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
set(handles.Play,'UserData','Pause');
```

In the play call back function, the video will be paused when 'UserData' of play button is set to be 'Pause', which is done through dragging slider.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code to illustrate? thanks

Comment: I've added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener (see the [addlistener](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html?refresh=true) documentation) to the slider value and set the frame position in the callback function. For example, assuming you have a handle to the slider saved in a variable called `slider`:

```
addlistener( slider, 'Value', 'PostSet', @slider_callback );
```

This will execute the `slider_callback` function after the `Value` property is set by moving the slider.

In R2015b this listener is fired as the slider is moved rather than when you release the mouse button. Not sure if this detail affects your application.

Comment: I need to use information in handles in callback function, should I use @slider_callback or @slider_callback(handles) ?

Comment: Do you mean the handles structure that is returned by the guihandles function?

Comment: yes, the handle structure that is used to access each button and slider

Comment: Use the guihandles function within your callback instead of passing the handles structure. This way you ensure you have the most updated structure.